# What's the significance of the two 'Mool-Dwarkas' (in the Kodinar district, and in the Visavada) ? Which one is significant for Krishna devotees?

Tags: krishna, pilgrimage

There are two 'Mool Dwarkas'. One in the Kodinar district and another one in the Visavada. What is the significance of both? Which one is significant for Krishna devotees?

Planning to visit Somnath and Dwarka.

Which one should I cover?